# Current is flowing out of both base and collector of my BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt

I have a 2N2222A BJT transistor and I hooked it up like follows.

[image: circuit diagram]

I measured voltages at a couple of points (with respect to ground) and I drew them on the diagram. You can see (using Ohms law) that there is current flowing out of both the collector and emitter. Furthermore the voltage between the C and E pins was 0.

I cannot square this with the model from my textbook.
[image: typical common emitter characteristics]

Vce = 0, so that there should actually be no current entering the collector, let alone a large negative current like in my diagram.

Something to point out is that I have connected both C and E pins to ground. But I think that should be the same as a common emitter configuration with a 0 voltage on the C pin. The other thing is a 1MOhm resistor between emitter and ground, which does not appear in the common emitter topology.

Is this behavior explained by the characteristic curves in my textbook or are there other exotic effects going on?

Comment: What's your goal here?  In the circuit you have created you are basically operating that as a pair of diodes, not a transistor.  You've not really given the transistor any opportunity to be a transistor as you haven't created any sort of useful circuit utilizing a current path between collector and emitter.  If you want to see something useful, you need to put another source on the right and drastically reduce the emitter resistor.

Comment: It could be in line with the "transistor diode model". Have you looked if it explains your measurements.

Comment: NPN. You're injecting holes into into the P. Each PN makes a diode which you are forward biasing. Why would you not expect current to end up flowing out the collector any less than you would the emitter?

Comment: The goal is just to explain the behavior that I'm seeing. And I guess it should function as two diodes! I guess I wasn't thinking about it like that since I was focused on the characteristic plots from my textbook.

Comment: It's important to know the regions of operation over which you can apply simplified equations or typical characteristic curves. For example, for \$\beta\$ to be useful you need Vce to be more than a few hundred mV. If you blindly apply equations you'll sometimes get results that won't reflect reality.

Comment: Simple : both diodes are forward biased. Textbooks don't treat this very much because it's not very interesting or useful.

Comment: Well, when both junctions are forward biased, that is the saturation mode of operation for a BJT. That IS of considerable interest but normally VCE would not be zero. The collector of an NPN would be at slightly higher potential than the emitter (reversed for PNP). I don't see much use for this exact circuit, but saturated BJT is an important circuit.

Comment: How did you measure the voltages? Consider [Why does my multimeter show a wrong voltage over a large resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/287705/29811)